# how to remove a div with same ids but display='block' and display='none' in JAVascript

Tags: javascript

I have more than 1 divs
with same id, but one has diplay='block'
and others have display='none'.

I want to delete all the divs which have display='none'.

Kindly tell the easiest way.

Comment: don't use same ids for the elements, use `class` instead.

Comment: You can't have more than one element with a given id on a page. Fix that before you try to manipulate the page using JS.

Comment: Why? They're hidden. They're not hurting anyone. :-)

Comment: m generating html by ajax, so i m getting duplicate ids

Answer (score 6):

It is against W3 Standards to have more than one element in a document to have same id's.

Use class names instead. Unfortunately there is no javascript function to get elements by class name. I am afraid you will have to cycle through all the div elements(using getelementsbytagname) and then find out the necessary div.

However if you are using jquery you can use its selector and get the elements by class name and iterate through it.

```
$('.classname').each(function(index) {
   //check if display is none and delete it
  });
```

Comment: Not just the W3C standard, but also against the XHTML 1.1 doctype definition (which is, now that I think about it, a W3C standard).

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with **one line** of jquery code **if you want to go with it:**

```
$("div.the_div:hidden").remove();
```

That will remove all the divs due to JQuery's  **implicit iteration** that are hidden that is `display:none`

Make sure that you wrap above line of code in **ready** method of JQuery which fires as soon as DOM becomes ready. So it becomes:

```
$(function(){
    $("div.the_div:hidden").remove();
});
```

**Note:** Give your divs the class of `the_div` first.

Comment: I posted an answer here but I'll give you my vote, yours is better

Answer (score 2):

Any html element ID attribute must be unique. More on [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp). You should rewrite your html code to use classes instead of ids.

Answer (score 1):

first ID should be unique for the whole document, duplicate ID in the document is wrong practice.

about deleting elements who have the same style,if you can keep the styling in CSS class then it is better to create two classes one Hidden and other Displayed then use jQuery to select these elements from the selector and remove them eg

```
$(".hidden").remove();
```

but if it was inline you should select the elements and loop through them and see if the who has style = none remove it.
eg:
lets say all the elements you want to control have unified class instead of duplicate Id, lets say "MyDivs"
in jQuery

```
    $(".MyDivs").each(
    function(){
    if($(this).css("display") == "none")
    {
    $(this).remove();
    }
}
)
```

hope this helps