# javascript prototype getting a div wid id and display='none'

Tags: javascript

i am using protoype and i want to get the div wid id='div_3' and display='none'
means in a single line i want to find the element wid these two attribs

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683144/how-to-remove-a-div-with-same-ids-but-displayblock-and-displaynone-in-javas

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute already uniquely defines an element (assuming your markup is valid). So, all you need to do is select the element with id `div_3` - and *then* worry about its `display` CSS property, if you need to:

```
var $myDiv = $('div_3');
if($myDiv.getStyle('display')) {
    // do something
}
```